# Creating folder based on current date and save excel workbook based on Filter

Tags: excel, vba, do-while, save-as

I'm working on a database that will compile 4 recordsets together in order to output 3 excel worksheets into a single workbook for each workcenter or Office Symbol. This will be updated weekly and new workbooks produced at each update.

I've managed to stumble my way into creating the workbooks the way I want them. However, saving the files has become an issue. The beginning of this sub creates a folder using today's date. Everything following creates the individual reports. The issue comes when I attempt to use the "wb.Saveas". Instead of saving the reports with the name from the "Do While Not" in the created folder, it saves it using today's date and the "Do While Not" output (See attached images).

I also have an issue with the Select Queries (AD1, PT1 and LV1) not giving me consistent results. Instead of filtering to only 1 Office Symbol, some of the time I get 3 or 4 on one excel output.

Thanks in advance for help with this.

Please excuse my lack of consistency with coding. I'm stumbling my way through this and I don't know the proper formatting etiquette.

[incorrect naming format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oYt7C.png)

```
Private Sub Export_Button_Click()
Dim sFolderName As String, sFolder As String
Dim sFolderPath As String

    sFolder = "C:\Users\1023491733A\Desktop\TEST\"
    sFolderName = Format(Now, "dd MMM yyyy")
    sFolderPath = "C:\Users\1023491733A\Desktop\TEST\" & sFolderName
    Set oFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    If oFSO.FolderExists(sFolderPath) Then
    MsgBox "Folder already exists  with today's date!", vbInformation, "VBAF1"
    Else
    MkDir sFolderPath
    MsgBox "Folder has created with today's date: " & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & sFolderPath, vbInformation, "VBAF1"
    End If


Dim db As DAO.Database
Set db = CurrentDb
Dim OS As DAO.Recordset
Set OS = db.OpenRecordset("Office_Symbols")
Dim AD As DAO.Recordset
Set AD = db.OpenRecordset("XLS-Airfield")
Dim PT As DAO.Recordset
Set PT = db.OpenRecordset("XLS-Fitness")
Dim LV As DAO.Recordset
Set LV = db.OpenRecordset("XLS-Leave")

Dim xl
Set xl = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Dim wb As Object
Set wb = xl.Workbooks.Add("C:\Users\1023491733A\Desktop\TEST\Template.xlsx")
Dim wr As Object
Set wr = wb.Worksheets("Airfield")
Dim ws As Object
Set ws = wb.Worksheets("Fitness")
Dim wt As Object
Set wt = wb.Worksheets("Leave")

        
   
Do While Not OS.EOF


    
    
    Dim AD1 As DAO.Recordset
    Set AD1 = db.OpenRecordset("SELECT [XLS-Airfield].* FROM [XLS-Airfield] WHERE ([XLS-Airfield].OFFICE_SYMBOL)='" & OS.Fields(0) & "';")
    Dim PT1 As DAO.Recordset
    Set PT1 = db.OpenRecordset("SELECT [XLS-Fitness].* FROM [XLS-Fitness] WHERE ([XLS-Fitness].OFFICE_SYMBOL) ='" & OS.Fields(0) & "';")
    Dim LV1 As DAO.Recordset
    Set LV1 = db.OpenRecordset("SELECT [XLS-Leave].* FROM [XLS-Leave] WHERE ([XLS-Leave].OFFICE_SYMBOL) ='" & OS.Fields(0) & "';")
   

    wr.Select
    wr.Range("A1").Select

    For Each fld In AD1.Fields
        xl.ActiveCell = fld.Name
        xl.ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
    Next

    AD1.MoveFirst
    
    wr.Cells(2, 1).CopyFromRecordset AD1
        
'Break

    ws.Activate
    ws.Range("A1").Select

    For Each fld In PT1.Fields
        xl.ActiveCell = fld.Name
        xl.ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
    Next
    
    PT1.MoveFirst
    
    ws.Cells(2, 1).CopyFromRecordset PT1

'Break

    wt.Activate
    wt.Range("A1").Select

    For Each fld In LV1.Fields
        xl.ActiveCell = fld.Name
        xl.ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
    Next

    LV1.MoveFirst
    
    wt.Cells(2, 1).CopyFromRecordset LV1


    







    Dim sFileName As String
    sFileName = OS.Fields(0)
    
wb.SaveAs sFolderPath & sFileName

Set AD1 = Nothing
Set PT1 = Nothing
Set LV1 = Nothing

OS.MoveNext

Loop

OS.Close
        
        wr.Rows("1:1").Font.Bold = True 'Row 1 Bold
        wr.Cells.EntireColumn.AutoFit  'Autofit all the columns
        ws.Rows("1:1").Font.Bold = True 'Row 1 Bold
        ws.Cells.EntireColumn.AutoFit  'Autofit all the columns
        wt.Rows("1:1").Font.Bold = True 'Row 1 Bold
        wt.Cells.EntireColumn.AutoFit  'Autofit all the columns

Set OS = Nothing
Set AD = Nothing
Set PT = Nothing
Set LV = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: Try `wb.SaveAs sFolderPath & "\" & sFileName`

Comment: I've tried this as well as 
sFolderPath = "C:\Users\1023491733A\Desktop\TEST\" & sFolderName & "\"
and both give me "Run-time error 1004"

Answer (score 0):

I have solved my issue. I'm not sure if it's the best solution but here are the changes I made.

Dim the objects was moved into the the Do While Not loop and each was set to nothing  before the OS.MoveNext.

```
Do While Not OS.EOF
   
       Dim xl As Object
       Set xl = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
       Dim wb As Object
       Set wb = xl.Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\1023491733A\Desktop\TEST\Template.xlsx")
       Dim wr As Object
       Set wr = wb.Worksheets("Airfield")
       Dim ws As Object
       Set ws = wb.Worksheets("Fitness")
       Dim wt As Object
       Set wt = wb.Worksheets("Leave")
```

I added a backslash to sFolderName as below which helped. And for some reason unknown to me, using two variables ("sfolderpath" and "OS.Fields(0)) would always give a run-time 1004 error. But inserting a constant between them seems to fix this issue but again I'm not sure why.

```
    sFolderName = (Format(Now, "dd MMM yyyy") & "\")
    Dim sfilename As String
    sfilename = sFolderPath & "TEST" & OS.Fields(0)
    wb.SaveAs sfilename
```

I understand the first fix since the loop was using the excel workbook from the previous iteration. But I can't wrap my head around why the sFileName fix worked. If anyone can explain this I would greatly appreciate it.